# Clicking on profile in top navbar goes to error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

- I'm in the latest version of Firefox on OSX.
- I'm logged in
- I'm looking at Meta (e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, but any page on meta.stackoverflow will do)

Clicking on the profile bit of the top navbar (i.e. the bit with my photo and badges) takes me to a 500 error page - the URL is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/582278/blowski.

AFAIK it's only started doing this today.

Comment: More precisely, the error occurs on the Activity tab on the profile of any user on meta sites, across the network.

Comment: No repro over here.

Comment: Can't reproduce on my profile or @Blowski's.

Comment: [Reported, fixed and explained at meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254031/259867)

Answer (score 3):

OK, looks like a cache problem. I just restarted Firefox and cleared all cache and now it's working.

Comment: [Nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254029/oops-something-bad-happened-loading-user-profiles-on-meta-sites)